# Is there a theorem which relates calculating the total number of a combinatorial object with picking one at random?

Tags: reference-request, combinatorics, recurrence-relation, randomness

A common algorithmic challenge is to generate an object of a certain kind, uniformly at random. For example, generating a random permutation of size $k$ from a given (multi)set of $N$ characters, as in [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/122158/sampling-of-subsets-with-repeat/122160#122160).

I've noticed that when solving such tasks, any algorithm for *calculating the number of such* combinatorial objects via a recurrence relation can be transformed into an algorithm to *generate* such combinatorial objects. My question is, is there a name for this technique? Is there a theorem which says when this is true?

**For example,** suppose I want to generate a random sequence of $n$ $1$s and $0$s, where there are no two adjacent $1$s. I can begin by letting $a[n]$ be the number of such sequences, and observe that
$$
a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2].
$$

(This is the Fibonacci relation.)
This allows me to efficiently calculate a table of $a[i]$ for $i = 1$ to $i = n$.
Now if I want to generate a random such sequence, all I have to do is:

**Step 1:** Generate a random value $r$ from $1$ to $a[n]$.

**Step 2:** Use the recurrence relation to locate a sub-term which corresponds to the $r$th sequence:

- If $r \le a[n-1]$, recursively find the $r$th sequence counted by $a[n-1]$, and append a $0$.
- Otherwise, if $a[n-1] < r \le a[n-1] + a[n-2]$, set $r' = r - a[n-1]$, and recursively find the $r'$th sequence counted by $a[n-2]$, and append a $01$.

What seems to be going on here is that, given any recurrence relation for $a[n]$, I can transform this into a recursive algorithm which returns the $r$th object counted by $a[n]$. I'm assuming this is well-known, so I would be interested in any references or classic results about this. In particular, this isn't just specific to the example $a[n]$, but should be true for *any* recurrence relation satisfying certain properties.

Also, I think this may be related to some research on random testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as [ranking and unranking functions](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions).  You are right about the correspondence between recurrence relations for counting and unranking algorithms.